# Word meaning "out of place"

Tags: synonyms

I'm looking for a single word that means "out of place":

? is to "out of place" as "anachronism" is to "out of time".

Comment: In the sense of *inappropriate or unsuitable*?

Comment: The word is ***misplaced***.

Comment: "Misplaced" is probably the word I'm looking for. I was thinking of a scene where a person is hiking on a wooded trail and finds a bank booth with an attendant offering to open accounts, process deposits, etc. The banker would be misplaced.

Comment: as "anachronism" is to "out of temporal order"

Comment: Sorethumbesque.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it requires a noun, then "**displacement**", "**misplacement**", or "**dislocation**" all seem analogous to an anachronism.

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/dislocation

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/misplacement

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/displacement